# Public method not returning the variable

Tags: java, return, return-value

Im new in Java why is my method not returning the variable I put. I want to use the return thing I dont want to use sysout but its not working.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    counter("this is a test");
}


public static int counter(String sentence) {
    int count = 0;
    while (CODE DELETED){
      count=count+1;
      MORE CODE DELETED
    }
    CODE DELETED
    return count;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to see? You don't want to use STDOUT so where do you expect to see it?

Comment: @BoristheSpider he means he doesn't want to add a print within the counter method itself.

Comment: @Shultuske that's not what the OP said.

Comment: @BoristheSpider not explicitly, but if he doesn't want to use it, why would he care that the variable is returned or not?

Comment: Presumably because the OP doesn't understand what return does. That's what I'm trying to get to the bottom of; where exactly is the misunderstanding. I think it's important to figure that out before posting an answer.

Comment: Presumably he does know what return does, otherwise he wouldn't be expecting a value returned. It's the assigning/using of the value he had trouble with

Answer (score 2):

It does return it, but you neither assign the value, nor do you use it.

Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = counter("this is a test");
    System.out.println("result = " + result);
}
```

Comment: You are right I forgot to call it in public static void main(String[] args) {
 using System.out.println(); Thanks!

Comment: You did call it. You didn't use it. The value was returned, but not accessible to use.

Answer (score 1):

The method *is* returning the value, but you are not doing anything with the returned value.

Maybe you misunderstand what "returning a value" means. It does not mean that the returned value is automatically printed to the console.

You'll have to put the returned value in a variable in the `main` method, and then you can for example print it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int value = counter("this is a test");
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

You can also print it directly, not storing it in a variable:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Print whatever the call to the method 'counter(...)' returns
    System.out.println(counter("this is a test"));
}
```